# Reading CSV giving different outputs in different computers

Tags: php

So in my platform i have a functionality which reads email, first name and last name from a csv file and then save them in database on to an array. All is working fine in my computers, but however in 2 of my co workers pc the list is returning 0 elements and it has 37, however running it in multiple browsers on my 2 computers it works perfectly fine. We are all using the same list to test.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                               <label>Nome da lista:</label>
                               <input class="form-control" typr="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" /></br>
                               <label>Lista (Ficheiro CSV):</label>
                               <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

                                 <button type="submit" id="enviar" name="submit" style="max-width:100px; background: #ed1a3d; margin-top:10px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-icon-split">
                                  Criar 
                                 </button>
                           </form>

<?php
global $user;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $user->criarLista($nome, $file);
    } else {
        $user->mensagem(1, "Não existe nenhum ficheiro");
    }

}
?>
```

And this is the criarLista function (Which means create list ):

```
public function criarLista($nome,$file){

        $user = $this->user;
        $get = $this->connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$user'");
        $fetch = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $user_id = $fetch['id'];

        if($insert = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO lista(user_id,nome) VALUES(?,?)")){
            $insert->bind_param("is", $user_id,$nome);
            $insert->execute();
            $list_id = $insert->insert_id;

            $file = preg_replace('#\\x1b[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]#', '', $file);
            $file = strip_tags($file);
            $lines = file($file);
            $emails = array();
            $fnames = array();
            $lnames = array();
            $linha = 0;
            foreach($lines as $line) {

                if($linha == 0){

                }else{

                    if (strpos($line, ',') !== false) {

                        $arr = explode(",", $line);
                        // Email \ FNAME | LAST

                        $emailx = trim($arr[0]);
                        $emailx = trim(preg_replace("/[\\n\\r]+/", "", $emailx));
                        array_push($emails,$emailx); 


                        if(isset($arr[1])){
                           $fname = trim($arr[1]);
                           $fname = str_replace('"','',$fname);
                           array_push($fnames,$fname); 
                        }

                        if(isset($arr[2])){
                           $lname = trim($arr[2]);
                           array_push($lnames,$lname); 
                        }

                    }else{
                       array_push($emails,trim($line)); 
                    }  

                }   

                $linha++;

            }

            array_map('trim', $emails);
            array_map('trim', $fnames);
            array_map('trim', $lnames);

            $emails = implode(",",$emails);
            $fnames = implode(",",$fnames);
            $lnames = implode(",",$lnames);

            if($insert_list = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO listas(lista_id,email,primeiro_nome,ultimo_nome) VALUES(?,?,?,?)")){
                $insert_list->bind_param("isss", $list_id,$emails,$fnames,$lnames);
                $insert_list->execute();

                $this->mensagem(2,"Lista adicionada com sucesso");

            }else{
                echo 
                '
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    Erro: '.$this->connect->error.'
                </div>
                ';
            }


        }else{

            echo 
            '
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                Erro: '.$this->connect->error.'
            </div>
            ';

        }    

    }
```

Is there anything that may create this incompability between some computers?

Comment: 99% sure the problem is in how they are creating the file.  Either they're saving it as the wrong format or adding columns where they shouldn't etc.  Have them email you the files and compare them to a file that does work.

Comment: @JeffUK The file we are testing is the same, no difference between them..

Comment: Something to do with not using `move_uploaded_file()`? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @kerbholz But the thing is that i did not want to save any local file , i just want to read it in temp and then let it go, but can be this that is causing the issue?

Comment: Can it be because of different line endings ? E.g. MacOS vs Linux/Windows ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Both my laptop and desktop are Mac, i tried on 2 other mac aswell from the designers which did not read the file, magicly it works perfectly on both of mine , i tried also on a windows laptop which did work. I think that there may be some kind of issue that is preventing it from being read

Comment: Could it be related to file permissions? What is the result of `filesize()` and what is the size of the `$lines` array? Also check the value of `$lines[0]`

Comment: @IVOGELOV What do you mean with file permissions? On the website server or the computer related with uploading?  Answering to the size it displays correctly for me, however for thoose other 2 colaborators attemp i can only try tomorrow, but it's really bugging me as it should work as same for all the computer, reading the code on OP can you identify something that could cause any incompability? It's just simple pure file reading and then i split the fail based on email, first name , last name and build an array, then i implode it and place it on the db..

Comment: I refer to file permissions on the server. Since you are uploading the file to the server it is important that the size of the uploaded file as seen by the PHP script is the same each time you or your colleagues upload the given CSV file. If the size is different when the file is uploaded from a particular PC - this means that the issue is in the PC and not in the server configuration.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I just changed a bit the upload and now i save the file online and read from there, but seems like its the same thing, the file has the same exact size, is just the script that has different outcomes

Comment: Computers are deterministic machines - if your script receives the same data every time it is not possible to produce different outcome. Put some `var_dump` to show you each`$line` and then each `$arr` - you will quickly see if there are differences when you upload from different computers.

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes they have different outcomes in the array, lines  for example , on other computers it only reads as 1 line , but im reading now the file from the system so this should not .happen anymore